# doubly linked list problem with removal and push back maybe

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

In the main function, I tried to push front couple numbers and push back couple numbers and then remove pos = 0 and pso = 1. However, in the output, remove at pos = 0 and remove at pos = 1 prints out number 5 and number 7 which are wrong. It should be 4 and 2. I cannot find which part I am wrong. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef MYDLL_H
#define MYDLL_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} node_t;

typedef struct DLL
{
    int count;     
    node_t *head; 
    node_t *tail; 
} dll_t;

dll_t *create_dll()
{

    dll_t *myDLL = (dll_t*)malloc(sizeof(dll_t));
    if (myDLL == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    myDLL->count = 0;
    myDLL->head = NULL;
    myDLL->tail = NULL;
    return myDLL;
}


int dll_empty(dll_t *l)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
}
    if (l->count == 0 && l->head == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int dll_push_front(dll_t *l, int item)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    node_t* new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    new->data = item;
    new->next = l->head;
    new->previous = NULL;

    if (l->head != NULL) { //set new prev for the previous head before pushing. 
        l->head->previous = new;
    } 
    l->head = new; // reset the new head for l.
    l->count++;
    return 1;
}


int dll_push_back(dll_t *l, int item)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    node_t* new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    new->data = item;
    new->previous = l->tail;
    new->next = NULL;

    if(l->tail != NULL) {
        l->tail->next = new;
    } else {
        l->head = new;
    }
    l->tail = new;
    l->count++;
    return 1;
}

int dll_pop_front(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL || t->head == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    node_t* pop_pointer = t->head; 
    int pop_item = pop_pointer->data; 
    t->head = pop_pointer->next; // set new head. 
    if (t->head != NULL) {
        t->head->previous = NULL;
    } else { // t->head = NULL cuz only one item and after popping, the t->head is null. 
        t->tail = NULL; // else if t->head = NULL, then t->tail also should be NULL.
    }
    if (t->head == NULL) {
        t->tail = NULL;
    }
    t->count--;
    free(pop_pointer);
    return pop_item;
}


int dll_pop_back(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL || t->head == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    node_t* pop_pointer = t->tail;
    int pop_item = pop_pointer->data; 
    t->tail = pop_pointer->previous; 
    if (t->tail != NULL) {
        t->tail->next = NULL;
    } else {
        t->head = NULL;
    }
    if (t->head == NULL) {
        t->tail = NULL;
    }
    t->count--;
    free(pop_pointer);
    return pop_item;
}

int dll_insert(dll_t *l, int pos, int item)
   {
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pos >= l->count || pos < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    node_t* new = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    new->data = item;
    if(pos == 0) {
        return dll_push_front(l, item);
    }

    node_t* pointer = l->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
        pointer = pointer->next; 
    }
//ex: pos = 1, no for loop, pointer still head. 
    new->previous = pointer; 
    new->next = pointer->next; 
    pointer->next->previous = new; 
    pointer->next = new; 
    l->count++;
    return 1;
}


int dll_get(dll_t *l, int pos)
{
   if (l == NULL) {
    return -1;
   } 
   if (pos < 0 || pos >= l->count) {
    return 0;
   }
   node_t* pointer = l->head;
   for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
    pointer = pointer->next;
   }
   return pointer->data;
}


int dll_remove(dll_t *l, int pos)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= l->count) {
        return 0;
    }
    node_t* pointer = l->head;
    node_t* prev = NULL; // first node prev is null. 
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        prev = pointer;
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    if (prev == NULL) { // first item.
        l->head = pointer->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = pointer->next;
    }
    if (pointer->next != NULL) {
        pointer->next->previous = prev;
    }
// if we are removing the tail node
    if (pointer == l->tail) {
        l->tail = prev;
    }
    int removed_value = pointer->data;
    free(pointer);
    l->count--;
    return removed_value;
}



int dll_size(dll_t *t) {   
    if (t == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return t->count;
}

void free_dll(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (t == NULL) {
        free(t);
        return;
    }
    node_t* pointer = t->head;
    while(pointer != NULL) {
        node_t* pointer2 = pointer; 
        pointer = pointer->next;
        free(pointer2); 
    }
    free(t);
}

#endif
```

Comment: Not going to try to find everything as this is not a full suite. However, when you add the first node to the head OR the tail, you need to set BOTH head & tail pointers to this orginal individual... (PS: You can replace all of `create_dll()` with a single `calloc( 1, sizeof....)` )

Comment: As @Fe2O3 said. You need to set `tail` in `dll_push_front()` when inserting first entry in the list

Comment: So in the push front, i need to set tail to equals to head when inserting first entry right?

Comment: @luke, yes. that is correct

Comment: @luke Posted a larger code block, I see... You've done fairly well. However, poking the first node onto the list with `dll_push_front()` still doesn't set the `tail` to point to the one-and-only node that is both `head` and `tail`. Also: `dll_insert()` allocates a node that it doesn't use if `pos(ition)` is 0... That's a memory leak. Maybe shift the code around just a bit if `pos == 0` and you use your other function...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you so much. I found that leak! Really helpful!!!!