# doubly linked list test error message: free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am a beginner in c and I tried to implment doubly linked list including pop, insert, remove funtions. I got the test error messages and it said "Approaching: Testing popping elements from the list, both ends Test Failed: free(): double free detected in tcache 2".

The implementation of my code is shown below

```
#ifndef MYDLL_H
#define MYDLL_H

#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} node_t;

typedef struct DLL
{
    int count;    
    node_t *head; 
    node_t *tail; 
} dll_t;

// Creates a DLL
dll_t *create_dll()
{
    dll_t* myDLL = (dll_t*)malloc(sizeof(dll_t));
    if (myDLL == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //initial pointer point to self
    // myDLL->next=myDLL->previous=myDLL;
    // return myDLL;

    // set fileds to default values
    myDLL->count = 0;
    myDLL->head = NULL; 
    myDLL->tail = NULL; 

    return myDLL;
}

// DLL Empty
// Check if the DLL is empty
// Returns -1 if the dll is NULL.
// Returns 1 if true (The DLL is completely empty)
// Returns 0 if false (the DLL has at least one element enqueued)
int dll_empty(dll_t *l)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (l->count == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// push a new item to the front of the DLL ( before the first node in the list).
// Returns -1 if DLL is NULL.
// Returns 1 on success
// Returns 0 on failure 
int dll_push_front(dll_t *l, int item)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    node_t* newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t)); 
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    newNode->data = item; 
    newNode->previous = NULL; 
    if (l->head == NULL) {
        l->head = newNode;
        l->tail = newNode; 
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = l->head; 
        l->head = newNode; 
        l->head->previous = newNode;
    
    l->count++;
    return 1;
}

// push a new item to the end of the DLL (after the last node in the list).
// Returns -1 if DLL is NULL.
// Returns 1 on success
// Returns 0 on failure ( i.e. we couldn't allocate memory for the new node)
// (i.e. the memory allocation for a new node failed).
int dll_push_back(dll_t *l, int item)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    node_t* newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    newNode->data = item; 
    newNode->next = newNode->previous = NULL; 
    if (l->tail == NULL) {
        l->head = newNode;
        l->tail = newNode; 
        newNode->previous = NULL;
    }
    else {
        newNode->previous = l->tail; 
        l->tail->next = newNode; 
        l->tail = newNode; 
    }
    l->count++;
    return 1;
}

// Returns the first item in the DLL and also removes it from the list.
// Returns -1 if the DLL is NULL.
// Returns 0 on failure, i.e. there is noting to pop from the list.
// Assume no negative numbers in the list or the number zero.
int dll_pop_front(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (t->count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        node_t* temp = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        temp = t->head; 
        int data = temp->data; 
        t->head = t->head->next;
        free(temp); 
        t->count--;

        if (t->count == 0) { 
            t->tail = NULL; 
        }

        return data;
    }

}

// Returns the last item in the DLL, and also removes it from the list.
// Returns a -1 if the DLL is NULL.
// Returns 0 on failure, i.e. there is noting to pop from the list.
// Assume no negative numbers in the list or the number zero.
int dll_pop_back(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (t->count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        node_t* temp = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        temp = t->tail; 
        int data = temp->data;
        t->tail = t->tail->previous; 
        free(temp);
        t->count--;

        if (t->count == 0) { 
            t->head = NULL; 
        }

        return data;
    }

}

// Inserts a new node before the node at the specified position.
// Returns -1 if the list is NULL
// Returns 1 on success
// Retruns 0 on failure:
//  * we couldn't allocate memory for the new node
//  * we tried to insert at a negative location.
//  * we tried to insert past the size of the list
//   (inserting at the size should be equivalent as calling push_back).
int dll_insert(dll_t *l, int pos, int item)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (pos == l->count) {
        return dll_push_back(l, item);
    }

    if (pos == 0) {
        return dll_push_front(l, item);
    }

    if (pos < 0 || pos > l->count) {
        return 0;
    }

    node_t* temp = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(temp == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    temp->data = item;
    node_t* curr = l->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    temp->previous = curr;
    temp->next = curr->next;
    temp->next->previous = temp;
    curr->next = temp;
    l->count++;

    return 1;
}

// Returns the item at position pos starting at 0 ( 0 being the first item )
// Returns -1 if the list is NULL
//  (does not remove the item)
// Returns 0 on failure:
//  * we tried to get at a negative location.
//  * we tried to get past the size of the list
// Assume no negative numbers in the list or the number zero.
int dll_get(dll_t *l, int pos)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pos < 0 || pos > l->count) {
        return 0;
    }

    node_t* curr = l->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return curr->data;
}

// Removes the item at position pos starting at 0 ( 0 being the first item )
// Returns -1 if the list is NULL
// Returns 0 on failure:
//  * we tried to remove at a negative location.
//  * we tried to remove get past the size of the list
// Assume no negative numbers in the list or the number zero.
// Otherwise returns the value of the node removed.
int dll_remove(dll_t *l, int pos)
{
    if (l == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (pos == l->count) {
        return dll_pop_back(l);
    }

    if (pos == 0) {
        return dll_pop_front(l);
    }

    if (pos < 0 || pos >= l->count) {
        return 0;
    }

    node_t* curr = l->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    node_t* temp = curr->next;
    curr->next = curr->next->next;
    int data = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    l->count--;
    return data;
}

// DLL Size
// Returns -1 if the DLL is NULL.
// Queries the current size of a DLL
int dll_size(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    return t->count;
}

// Free DLL
void free_dll(dll_t *t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    node_t* curr = t->head;
    node_t* next;
   
    while (curr != NULL) {
        next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;

    }
    free(t);
}

#endif
```

I tried using valgrind which showed memory leaks but I still don't know how to fix this

Comment: Some issues in `dll_pop_back()` and `dll_pop_front()`. There is a memory leak. Also the prev/next element of the node being deleted is not updated properly

Comment: Take a close look in `dll_push_front()`... The existing 'head' node is not set to point 'previous' as should be done... Operations are not in the correct sequence... That's a start...

Comment: `dll_remove()` is obviously incomplete... PS: Don't put code into header files. Put declarations there, but put code into source code files...

Comment: I knew this looked familiar [doubly linked list problem with removal and push back maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75318787/3422102) - but no answer there, so this isn't a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are multiple issues in your code.

In `dll_push_front()`, `l->head->previous = newNode;` line should be placed before setting the `l->head` to `newNode`. Otherwise the newly created node will point to itself as previous node. Also you missed the ending `}` of else block.

In `dll_pop_front()`, you are doing a `malloc()` and in the next line overwrites that pointer (`temp`) which introduces a memory leak. You don't need the malloc here. Also the 2nd element (next to the element being deleted) should be updated to set its `previous` link to NULL. Same type of issues present in `dll_pop_back()`. Also if `t->count` becomes 0 shouldn't both the `t->tail` and `t->head` set to be NULL?

In `dll_remove()`, you are accessing `curr->next->next` but `cur->next` could be NULL. For example, lets say the list have 2 nodes. So, the `count` would be 2. But if someone calls `dll_remove()` with `pos` 1, the `curr` will point to the last element. Same issue for accessing `temp->next`.